# which button is pressed in dynamically created button 2d array

Tags: c#, arrays, dynamic-programming, buttonclick

I have a 2d array of LEDButton : Button.

I want to find out the index [x,y] of each buttons the user clicks.

I am new to Windows Forms and not used to working outside of a console so these GUI objects are very unfamiliar to me.

```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LEDButton[,] leds = new LEDButton[11, 11];
        for (int x = 0; x < leds.GetUpperBound(0); x++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("x = " + x);
            for (int y = 0; y < leds.GetUpperBound(1); y++)
            {
                leds[x, y] = new LEDButton()
                {
                    Name = String.Format("Button{0}{1}", x, y),
                    TabIndex = 40 * x + y,
                    Location = new Point(40 * y + 50, 40 * x + 50)
                   
                };
                leds[x, y].pointx = x;
                leds[x, y].pointy = y;
            }
        }

        // add buttons to controls
        for (int x = 0; x < leds.GetUpperBound(0); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < leds.GetUpperBound(1); y++)
            {
                Controls.Add(leds[x, y]);
                leds[x, y].Click += Form1_Click;
            }
        }

    public class LEDButton : Button
    {
        public const int LEDWidth = 20;
        public const int LEDHeight = 20;
        public int pointx = 0;
        public int pointy = 0;
       
        public LEDButton()
        {
            BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 64, 0);
            ForeColor = Color.Black;
            FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            Size = new Size(LEDWidth, LEDHeight);
            UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.Click += LEDButton_Click; //throws error
        }
    }
```

Comment: The pointx and pointy of that LEDbutton class are enough to find the button in the array

Comment: The `sender` parameter is `Form1_Click` will tell you which button you have.  Cast to `LEDButton` and inspect the Name property.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found my answer with the help of Lars.

Code should be

```
    private void Form1_Click(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LEDButton btn = sender as LEDButton;
        listBox2.Items.Add(btn.Name);
    }
```